# How to modify the style of "select" in html

Tags: html, css, web

I want to use some font in "select" like this:

```
<select style="font-family:Coming Soon;font-size:18px;">
```

The test result like this:

[image: IE11 and firefox]

In firefox and IE11, it looks right. However, in chrome and safari：

[image: chrome and safari]

Can you tell me what's wrong please?

Comment: Please provide code samples and/or link to a `jsfiddle`

Comment: sorry,code like this:

Comment: <select style="font-family=Coming Soon;font-size=18px;">

Comment: may be this helps you http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=137692#c68

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you're using google fonts to style the select items. If so, then you'll have to add the link as http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coming+Soon' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> inside   and then apply font-family style to the select item.